# Change my Winform button behavior when hover, click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

Please take a look at this implementation from `Telerik`:

[image]

When hover:

[image]

When click:

[image]

Can I implement it without using any 3rd party program ?

Comment: Create custom control.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: @Nimesh if you don't know what language is, you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example to demonstrate how to create your custom control.

Create a UserControl and give the name **Sample** and place the following code in .cs file.

```
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
public partial class Sample : UserControl
{
    private string _text;
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
        }
    }
    private bool _mouseDown = false;
    private bool _mouseHover = false;
    private bool _invalidateRequired = true;

    public Sample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        _mouseDown = true;
        _invalidateRequired = true;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        _mouseDown = false;
        _invalidateRequired = true;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        _mouseHover = true;
        if (_invalidateRequired)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
            _invalidateRequired = false;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        _mouseHover = false;

        this.Invalidate();
        _invalidateRequired = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
        Color bg = Color.White;
        Color fr = Color.Gray;
        Color br = Color.FromArgb(173, 178, 173);
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            bg = Color.FromArgb(24, 162, 231);
            fr = Color.White;
        }
        if (_mouseHover)
            br = Color.FromArgb(24, 162, 231);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bg), r);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(br, 3), r);
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(fr), r, sf);            
    }
}
```

[Code with Designer.cs](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1568)

Comment: What to do with InitializeComponent() inside this class ? (The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context)

Comment: If you have added user control then you don't need to create InitializeComponent because it is already defined in designer.cs file.  make sure you have selected UserControl not a class.

Comment: Why when change Button FlatStyle from Standard to Flat the default color changed into gray ?